# How to do this in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a List of MyClass and in the main page I have 10 controls which will display the information about that list of Items. What I want is to check the count of the items in the List and then make the excess controls invisible. Now I'm using this code but is there an easier way of doing this?

```
 if (myList.Count > 0)
 {
      Control1.MyClassInfo = myList[0];
      if (myList.Count > 1)
      {
           Control2.MyClassInfo = myList[1];
           if (myList.Count > 2)
           {
                // and like that till 10
           }
           else
           {
                Control3.Visible = false;
                Control4.Visible = false;
                // till 10
           }
       }
       else
       {
           Control2.Visible = false;
           Control3.Visible = false;
           // till 10
       }
  }
  else
  {
       Control1.Visible = false;
       Control2.Visible = false;
       Control3.Visible = false;
       // and then till 10
  }
```

Comment: Is it a one to one relationship. As in does each item in the myclass list correspond to a control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just add your controls in a list (ordered).

Something like that

```
var controlList = new List<Control>{ Control1, Control2, Control3 /*etc*/};


var count = myList.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < controlList.Count; i++) {
  controlList[i].Visible = count > i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, and thanks to everyone which tried to help me

Answer (score 3):

You could create a list of your controls

```
List<Control> MyControls = new List<Control>{Control1, Control2,..,Control10};
```

and then

```
foreach(var C in MyControls)
    C.Visible=false;

for(int i=0; i<myList.Count; i++)
    C[i].Visible=true;
```

Comment: Well, Raphael's answer is even better :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: for the more advanced coders here, this *technique* is called the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Basically, that's it. But you can improve on that basic concept in two ways:

1) use a collection

```
List<Control> _controls1to10;
```

Put your controls into that collection and write a method like this:

```
private void setVisibility(List<Control> _controls, bool visible)
{
    foreach (Control c in _controls1to10)
    {
        c.Visible = visible;
    }
}
```

This will make things easier.

2) use boolean expressions instead of nested `if`s, like this:

```
bool hasElements = myList.Count > 0;
bool hasMoreThan1 = myList.Count > 1;

// ... and so on
```

This means that you have *master switches* at the top and use them in the following code. This is a *fantasy example* to clear the concept but does not apply to your code:

```
bool isEditable = User.LoggedIn && SystemState.Maintenance == false && item.Count > 0;

editButton.Visible = isEditable;
dropList.Visible = !isEditable;
```